# how to update a record in the table to insert a comma and a value and its value in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have a table school with fields : no.reg and item
like below :

table school

```
no.reg= A
item  = book.
no.reg= B
item  = chair.
```

i want to insert record city with comma where no.reg = A
the result :

```
no.reg= A
item  = book , ruler, eraser.
no.reg= B
item  = chair
```

how to create a query for that ??

Answer (score 1):

```
update school
set item = 'book, ruler, eraser'
where [no.reg] = 'A'
```

or if you want to append a certain value to what exists already, just concatenate what you want

```
update school
set item = item + ', ruler, eraser'
where [no.reg] = 'A'
```